# Where can one access Aland's 23rd edition which was used for the first edition of the New American Standard Bible (NASB)?

Tags: resource-request, nasb

Where can one access Aland's *Novum Testamentum Graece*, 23rd edition, which was used for the first edition of the New American Standard Bible (NASB), according to this [PDF](http://bibleroads.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/bible_translation_comparisons.pdf)?

Comment: Doesn't have to be online, although that's preferable. Does anyone still sell print versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 23rd edition of Nestle-Aland was published in 1957, and unfortunately, Google Books often does not have preview available for books of this age. [This edition is no exception](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mf2umgEACAAJ), at least right now. It thus appears that used book stores are going to be your only option.

Depending on your country, the most appropriate online book shop may vary.  [Abe Books](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?an=aland&sts=t&tn=novum+testamentum) is a good bet in the US at least.  A [search for 1957](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?an=aland&kn=1957&tn=novum+testamentum) editions currently reveals one potential match.